# Displaying multiple (inputed) links on a page

Tags: php, html, arrays, input, output

I am trying to write a webpage program that (in a previous PHP page called `member.php`) takes 2 inputs: a website's title and URL. Then upon submission, it takes you to another page and is supposed to print out the title in an `<a href>` linked to the URL. But when I go back to the `member.php` page to input another link, the previous link i put in earlier is written over by my new input. Why is this the case?

```
$titles = array();
$urls = array();

$title = $_POST['title'];
$url = $_POST['url'];

if ($url && $title) {
    array_push($titles, $title);
    array_push($urls, $url);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); ++$i) {
    $getTitle = $titles[$i];
    $getUrl = $urls[$i];

    if ($getTitle && $getUrl) {
        echo "<br>".'<a href = "http://' . $getUrl . '" target="_blank">'.$getTitle.' </a>' . "<br>";       
    }
}
```

Comment: use session to store your data.

Comment: You can store your data to a database if you are using one, this way you can use in the future too or use session  as "jewelhuq" said if you are using it for a temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are running your member.php, you are running

```
$urls = array();
```

which is resetting the contents of the array. It isn't overwriting the previous one, the previous one just isn't in memory anymore after you navigate away.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple IF statement to make sure you're not rewriting your array:

```
if (!$urls) {
$url = $_POST['url'];
}
```

There. Now it will only be written if it doesn't exist. Simply add on to this array, now that you know it already exists.

Also, consider using session variables. They expire when the user leaves your page.

[You can read about sessions here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)